# How to load 32 bit constant to a register without using LUI

Tags: assembly, mips

I am trying to load a 32-bit constant 0x1234ABCD to register `$t0` in MIPS assembly. However, I am not able to use `lui` to do so. My instinct is to use two `addi`, but I am not sure how to do so. I would necessarily need 2 or more to get the 32 bits of information. I need to get the upper bits set somehow without `lui`. What is a good way to approach replicating `lui` without using it?

Comment: Normally, we would do `lui $t0 0x1234` `ori $t0, 0xABCD`. How do I load the upper bits without load upper immediate?

Comment: did you look at the instruction set? what part of the documentation do you not understand?

Comment: Be imaginative: we can use add, subtract, shift, multiply on smaller constants to achieve larger ones.

Comment: @ErikEidt I didn't realize how powerful this is. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use for example `ori` combined with `sll` to load a 32 bit constant in 3 instructions without using `lui`:

```
  ori $t1, $zero, 0x1234  # load the upper half in the lower bits of $t1
  sll $t1, $t1, 16        # move them to the upper half
  ori $t1, $t1, 0xABCD    # combine with the lower half
```

Comment: Another way to phrase this is that `lui` can be exactly emulated with `ori` / `sll`-by-16.  Or with `addiu` since you're shifting out the high half, so it doesn't matter where you got zero- or sign-extension into the high half.